# Testing $interval in Jasmine/ Karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I have a simple factory

```
angular.module('myApp.dice',[]).factory('Dice', ['$interval', function($interval){
    return {
      rollDice: function(){
        return $interval(function(c){
               count++;
          }, 100, 18, false, 0);
      }
    };
}]);
```

In my test case I have

```
describe('rolling dice', function(){
      var promise, promiseCalled = false, notify = false;
      beforeEach(inject(function(){
        promise = Dice.rollDice();
        promise.then(function(){
          promiseCalled = true;
        });

      }));

      it('should invoke a promise', inject(function(){
        expect(promise).toBeDefined();
      }));

      it('should set promiseCalled', inject(function($rootScope, $interval){


        expect(promiseCalled).toEqual(true);
      }));
    });
```

How do I trigger the interval or resolve the promise? to get the test to be true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PyjfPSqEM8k8wflfgJec?p=preview)

You need to use ['$interval.flush'](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) from angularjs-mocks and then test for the result. I've taken the liberty to assign `count` to the dice object because it's undefined in your code sample.

Is there any reason why `$interval` is called with `invokeApply = false`? because then you have to manually call `$apply`.

The test case would be:

```
describe('rolling dice', function(){
    var $interval, $rootScope, dice;

    beforeEach(module('plunker'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$interval_, _$rootScope_, _Dice_){
      $interval = _$interval_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      dice = _Dice_;
    }));

    it('should increment count', inject(function(){
      dice.rollDice();
      // Move forward by 100 milliseconds
      $interval.flush(100);
      // Need to call apply because $interval was called with invokeApply = false
      $rootScope.$apply();
      expect(dice.count).toBe(1);
    }));
  });
```

with factory:

```
app.factory('Dice', ['$interval', function($interval){
    var self= {
      count: 0,
      rollDice: function(){
        return $interval(function() {
              self.count++;
          }, 100, 18, false, 0);
      }
    };
    return self;
}]);
```

EDIT:
I prefer testing the result of a function call but perhaps you have a use case for testing that a promise function is called so this might be what you're looking for. From the angular docs on `$interval` it says it returns

> A promise which will be notified on each iteration.

Keyword being **notified**. And from the [promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) the arguments for `then` are

```
then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)
```

i.e. the third call back function `notifyCallback` is called for each iteration of `$interval`. So the test would look something like this:

```
it('should set promiseCalled', function(){
  var promiseCalled = false;
  dice.rollDice().then(null, null, function() {
    promiseCalled = true;
  });
  $interval.flush(100);
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect(promiseCalled).toBe(true);
});
```

If you want to test for a resolved promise, then it would look something like this:

```
it('should resolve promise', function(){
  var promiseCalled = false;
  var resolvedData = null;
  $q.when('Some Data').then(function(data) {
    promiseCalled = true;
    resolvedData = data;
  });
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect(promiseCalled).toBe(true);
  expect(resolvedData).toBe('Some Data');
});
```

I've updated the plunker with these test cases.

Comment: Aaaahhhh....thanks. In previous code I had `$interval.flush` but the `$rootScope.$apply` is something new....

Comment: I just realise that this question while solves a problem does not answer a pertinent question.... How do I test the *promise callback* event return from `$interva()`

Comment: @Kendall Updated answer to address your last comment